# Use Jquery to sum values of a specific key in json from a form value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a script which constructs a json object and assigns it to a form text element like so :

```
<input id="clientList" type="hidden" value="[{"clientID":"1","clientType":"0","clientPrice":"450.00","tourID":"9","insuranceAvailable":"0"},{"clientID":"2","clientType":"2","clientPrice":"0.00","tourID":"9","insuranceAvailable":"0"}]">
```

I need (with Jquery or JS), sum up all the clientPrice keys in that string.

The code I'm trying is :

```
var totalRoomPrices = 0;

var travellerPricesToSum = JSON.stringify($('#clientList').serializeArray());

$.each(travellerPricesToSum, function () {
     totalRoomPrices += this.clientPrice;
});

console.log(totalRoomPrices);
```

Can anyone provide some insight as to what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: It's `$('#clientList').val()` to get the value

Comment: And you want to `JSON.parse` it, not stringify

Comment: I don't need the value of #clientList. I need to sum all the clientPrice values in that json form value

Comment: And how are you getting that JSON, `serializeArray()` gives you an array with names and values, but you only need the value

Comment: Jeezes -> https://jsfiddle.net/xLucx8j6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You need to parse the `value` as it is a string representation of the `json`. `JSON.stringify` will convert `object` to `string` which is not the case here. Also note, `"` inside string wrapped in `"` will break the string, Either escape them or use `'` inside `"` or vice versa.

As values are `strings`, `+=` will con-cat them. To get the addition working(considering floating values), use `parseFloat` to convert them in `float`

Try this:

```js
var totalRoomPrices = 0;
var travellerPricesToSum = JSON.parse($('#clientList').val());
$.each(travellerPricesToSum, function() {
  totalRoomPrices += parseFloat(this.clientPrice);
});
alert(totalRoomPrices);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="clientList" type="hidden" value='[{"clientID":"1","clientType":"0","clientPrice":"450.00","tourID":"9","insuranceAvailable":"0"},{"clientID":"2","clientType":"2","clientPrice":"0.00","tourID":"9","insuranceAvailable":"0"}]'>
```

Comment: This apparently gets them but outputs them like this : 0450.00220.00320.00 in the console

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have same style of quotes inside a value attribute. You will have to find another way to encode structured data in a string inside a value attribute, I've seen people use | and : characters as delimeters and obviously you will have to write your own parser using `str.split()`.

edit: Obviously, holding entire JSON string is also an option if you mix single and double quotes as per the other answer.